# What is the meaning of last_modified_timestamp in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, information-schema, database-metadata

I am running the below query, trying to understand the meaning of last_modified_timestamp. Is it when the data in the table was last updated (DML operation) or when the table structure was last modified (DDL operation).

```
SELECT * FROM dataset_name.__TABLES__;
```

Comment: I think you are asking about last_modfied_time  from dataset_name.__TABLES__is . This time is when the table was last updated. This could be either you have executed a DML operation on the table or you have modified the table for example an alter table statement. You can test this by yourself to get a better understanding.  You may want to  check using select  TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(last_modified_time) AS last_modified_time from dataset_name.__TABLES__

Answer (score 0):

As per the official documentation at:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/information-schema-tables

`LAST_MODIFIED_TIME` is "*The time when the data was most recently written to the partition*".